# Passing coordinates of location into google places query string

Tags: iphone, core-location

In my application i am able to get coordinates of my current location. But there is google places string like

```
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=52.577798767,-2.124885567&radius=500&types=bank&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCcC9pmri9XGOgydfsaadq37cmcb6fsd80"
```

Now how can i pass my dynamic coordinates (if i change my location my coordinates would be new) instead of fixed coordinates?

I want to use this string in

```
NSURL *googlePlacesURL = [NSURL URLWithString:googleUrl];

NSData *xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:googlePlacesURL];
```

a and b are

```
a = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LATITUDE: %f", location.coordinate.latitude];
//b = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LONGITUDE: %f", location.coordinate.longitude];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=%f,%f&radius=500&types=bank&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCcC9pmri9XGOgydfsaadq37cmcb6fsd80", longAsFloat, latAsFloat];
```

It might be hard to see in there, but I added "%f" in place of your long and lat which would allow you to pass them into the string. Then you can build your URL from your new custom string. Hope this helps.